# Skip concatenating the first value

Tags: python, concatenation

My question is fairly straight forward.

I am trying to concatenate a string with a returned value in a loop.
I don't want to add the text to the first occurrence, but to the rest.

Here is the sample code:

```
list_of_tables = {'k1': 'v1:v2',
'k2':'v3:v4',
'k3':'v5:v6',
'k4':'v7:v8',
'k5':None }

def gen_stmt(val1_name, val2_name):
    
    return 'some text '+ val1_name + ': '+ val2_name

stmt = ''
for k,v in list_of_tables.items():
    if v:
        pair_val = v.split(':') 
        fin_value += 'text I need to concat' + gen_stmt(*pair_val)
    return fin_value
```

What I need 'text I need to concat' for all the values of k2,k3,k4 and I need to run gen_stmt function for all the keys k1 ...k5

How can I concatenate all the values except the first value?

What I want the output to be

> some text v1 : v2 text I need to concat some text v3 : v4 text I need
> to concat some text v5 : v6 text I need to concat some text v7 : v8

Comment: take a slice of everything but the first value: `for k, v in list_of_tables.items()[1::]:`

Comment: Or perhaps `'text I need to concat'.join(...)`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I still need to pass k1 to gen_stmt function. I need that value

Comment: Your description isn't very clear - can you provide an example that shows exactly what you'd like as the end result, so people can give you suggestions on how to create that automatically?

Comment: I have provided my desired output to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break this out a bit more.

Make a loop that can transform each item into a string and add it to a list.

Then join the final list using whatever delimiter you need.

Try something like this:

```
string_values = []
for value in list_of_tables.values():
    if value:
        val1, val2 = value.split(':')
        string_value = gen_stmt(val1, val2)
        string_values.append(string_value)


print(' text I need to concat '.join(string_values))
```

To skip the first value, you can turn the values object into a list, and then slice off the first value:

And a one liner just for kicks:

```
print(' text I need to concat '.join(
    gen_stmt(*value.split(':'))
    for value in list_of_tables.values()
    if value
))
```

Comment: Its not working. It still prints text I need to concat for k1 too. This is what your code is returning. text I need to concatsome text v1: v2 text I need to concatsome text v3: v4 text I need to concatsome text v5: v6 text I need to concatsome text v7: v8. But what I need is, "some text v1: v2 text I need to concatsome text v3: v4 text I need to concatsome text v5: v6 text I need to concatsome text v7: v8"

Comment: @PaddyIyer Ah, I finally get what you mean. Use `' text I need to concat '` as the join argument.

Comment: Can you please show the code snippet. Thanks

Comment: @PaddyIyer Take a look at the answer again, it has been updated. It now produces `some text v1: v2 text I need to concat some text v3: v4 text I need to concat some text v5: v6 text I need to concat some text v7: v8`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. I did post a message earlier thanking you, but it got deleted.

Comment: @PaddyIyer no worries. Glad you were able to work it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a if-else statement which will filter first value from other elements of list.
my suggested code is like this.

```
list_of_tables = {'k1': 'v1:v2',
'k2':'v3:v4',
'k3':'v5:v6',
'k4':'v7:v8',
'k5':None }
def gen_stmt(val1_name, val2_name):
    
    return 'some text '+ val1_name + ':'+ val2_name

fin_value = ''
i = 0
for k,v in list_of_tables.items():
    if i == 0:
        pair_val = v.split(':')
        fin_value = gen_stmt(*pair_val) + " "          
    elif v:
        pair_val = v.split(':')
        fin_value += 'text I need to concat' + gen_stmt(*pair_val)
    i +=1

print(fin_value)
```

I think this very simple method but yes some extra line here added which make your code little bit long.